# How to calculate  95% confidence intervals for  partial eta squared and eta squared?

Tags: confidence-interval, effect-size

Following on from this question on [reporting eta squared](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15958/how-to-interpret-and-report-eta-squared-partial-eta-squared-in-statistically-s), I would like to report 95% CIs for my effect size point estimates (partial eta and eta squared values).

- What statistics do I need to know and is there a straight forward formula for calculation?

Comment: Very interesting. Normally I care alot about such things, but this one i have never thought of before.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15958/how-to-interpret-and-report-eta-squared-partial-eta-squared-in-statistically-s is a post with a good long answer providing some alternatives to eta (it's the answer that mentions Cohen several times). It's possible that these alternatives have a straightforward confidence interval.  Like rolando2, I find the question interesting, but don't know the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As a preliminary answer:

- This article seems to explain how to caculate confidence intervals for eta squared http://core.ecu.edu/psyc/wuenschk/SPSS/CI-R2-SPSS.doc using SPSS.

Comment: I'm impressed. I've seen some of Karl Weunsch's work before, on teaching statistics, and liked that too. Thanks for pointing this out, Jeremy.