# How to obtain a p-value for the eta measure of association?

Tags: correlation, p-value, association-measure

How can a P-Value be obtained for an analysis of Eta association?
Is there a reference for this?

Answer (score 3):

Given that your previous title mentioned nominal and numerical, I assume you are talking about the [effect size measure eta-squared](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15958/how-to-interpret-and-report-eta-squared-partial-eta-squared-in-statistically).
Eta-squared is the sample proportion of variance explained in a numerical variable by a categorical predictor variable. It is a biased estimate of the population variance explained (for a relatively unbiased estimate, I've often seen omega-squared recommended).

A p-value could be obtained by running a one-way between subjects ANOVA.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think "Statistics for Evidence-Based Practice and Evaluation" is a good book...
(Please save this image and see it)