# How to correlate scale and nominal variables in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I want to run a test in order to identify if there is any correlation between the length of in-hospital stay (Scale) and the kind of the procedure (Nominal with three options; abdominal, cardiac and other). Can you provide me with the right test from the Analyze menu in SPSS ?

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at [Correlation between a nominal (IV) and a continuous (DV) variable](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119835/correlation-between-a-nominal-iv-and-a-continuous-dv-variable/124618#124618)

Comment: In summary: we don't normally talk about "correlation" with a nominal variable, since there's no sense of "as X increases, Y increases" (how can X increase if it isn't ordered?). There are some analogous concepts you can apply to measure strength of association, such as eta-squared, but perhaps you are (or should be) more interested in [effect sizes](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15958/how-to-interpret-and-report-eta-squared-partial-eta-squared-in-statistically)